# Solution to simple Probability problem

Tags: probability

The problem:

> Jan and 5 other children are in a classroom. The principal of the school walks in and chooses two children at random. What is the probability that Jan is chosen?

My not-so-straightforward solution:
I first solve for the probability that Jan is not chosen (for caning, I think).

> Probability that Jan is not the first choice : 5/6
>
> Probability that Jan is not the second choice : 4/5 (since there is one less person to choose from)
>
> Probability that Jan is not the first choice AND not the second choice : 5/6 * 4/5 = 2/3
>
> Therefore, Probability that Jan is either the first choice OR the second choice : 1 - (2/3) = 1/3

This answer is correct according to the book but, is the solution right ?

Comment: Your solution is indeed "not-so-straightforward", but there is nothing wrong with it. Do you also have a "straightforward" solution?

Comment: "Straightforward" would be :
Probability that Jan is the first choice: 1/6
Probability that Jan is the second choice: 1/5
Probability that Jan is the first choice: 1/6
Probability that Jan is the first OR second choice: 1/6 + 1/5 = 11/30
Probability that Jan is the first AND second choice: 1/6 * 1/5 = 1/30
Probability that Jan is exclusively the first OR second choice = 11/30 - 1/30 = 1/3

Comment: Probability that Jan is the first choice or is *not* the first but is the second: $\frac 16 +\frac 56\frac15=\frac 13$

Comment: The order in which the persons are elected is irrelevant. Personally I would call that characteristic of a straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution looks perfect! here is another way to work it out
Total number of ways of choosing 2 children from 6 children = $\binom{6}{2} = 15$
Number of ways of choosing 1 other children along with Jan = $\binom{5}{1} = 5$
Probability of having Jan  =  $\dfrac{5}{15} = \dfrac{1}{3}$

Comment: I did not understand the notations you used. What does (6/2) mean ?

Comment: $\binom{6}{2}$ can also be represented as $^6C_2$. Are you familiar with permutations and combinations ? :)

Comment: @anon_16 It's the **binomial coefficient**.  $^{n}C_r = {n\choose r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

Comment: mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html

Comment: Oh I'm very bad at those. But, thanks for the answer !

Comment: @anon_16 $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient, and represents the amount of ways you can select k things from n objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is right.

Probability Jan is chosen is $\frac{\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{6}{2}}=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward solution.

If $2$ persons of $6$ are randomly (equal chances for everyone) elected, then any of the persons involved (Jan is one of them) has a chance of $\frac{2}{6}=\frac13$ to belong to those who are elected (and a chance of $\frac{4}{6}=\frac23$ to belong to those who are *not* elected).

Binomial coefficients are okay, but I only use them if they indeed make things more clear or easier to compute.